# bootstrap dropdown not working on heroku

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, heroku

I have bootstrap installed in my rails app, where everything is working correctly on local machine but as soon as i pushed it on heroku the dropdown and jQuery datepicker plugin stopped working

*My codes*

**Gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.3'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
group :production do
    gem 'pg'
    gem 'rails_12factor'
end
group :development, :test do
    gem 'sqlite3'
end

gem 'devise'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'mailboxer'
gem 'chosen-rails'
gem 'acts_as_votable', '~> 0.10.0'
gem 'public_activity'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'coffee-script-source', '1.8.0'
gem 'paperclip', '~> 4.3.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.5.1'
gem "font-awesome-rails"
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development


# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

**aplication.html.erb**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>ShiftInd</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/3.0.1/normalize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
  <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/
libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"
></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/style.css">
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-

        collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/shipments">Shiftind</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">


      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right col-md-3">
        <% if user_signed_in? %>
        <li class="<%= active_page(:inbox) %>">
    <%= link_to mailbox_inbox_path do  %>
        <span class="label label-danger pull-right"><%=unread_messages_count%></span>
        <em class="fa fa-envelope fa-lg"></em>
    <% end %>
  </li>

  <li class="dropdown" >
        <span class="notification-count" style = "padding: 5px;"><%= @comment.count.inspect %></span>
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><span class="notification-count">
            <span class="fa fa-bell fa-1x"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
             <li><% @comment.flatten.each do |c|%>
               <%= link_to comments_notification_update_path(:comment_id => c.id), :class => "notification"  do %><%@user = User.find c.user_id%><%= @user.full_name.capitalize%> added a <i class="fa fa-inr"></i> bid <%= c.content.split(//).first(5).join %>....<% end %><br><br>
               <% end %>
             </li>        
           </ul>
         </li>

         <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-

          expanded="false"><strong><font style="text-transform: capitalize;">Hi, <%= current_user.first_name %></strong></font><span 

          class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><%= link_to "Edit Your Details", edit_user_registration_path %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Log Out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :get %><li>
              <% else %>
              <li><%= link_to "Register", new_user_registration_path %></li>
              <li><%= link_to "Log in", new_user_session_path %></li>
              <% end %>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>




  <div class="text-center">
    <% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
    <%= content_tag(:div, msg, class: "alert alert-info") %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
  <%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

**aplication.js**

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or any plugin's vendor/assets/javascripts directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/rails/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//

//= require bootstrap
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require chosen-jquery
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .




$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).mousemove(function(e){
        TweenLite.to($('body'), 
            .5, 
            { css: 
                {
                    backgroundPosition: ""+ parseInt(event.pageX/8) + "px "+parseInt(event.pageY/'12')+"px, "+parseInt(event.pageX/'15')+"px "+parseInt(event.pageY/'15')+"px, "+parseInt(event.pageX/'30')+"px "+parseInt(event.pageY/'30')+"px"
                }
            });
    });


});

$(function() {
  $("#shipment_date").datepicker();
});
```

I tried many things but nothing helped. Any help will be great, thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you do a `heroku run rake assets:precompile` ?

Comment: Yup i did but it doesn't seems to work.... @sadaf2605

Answer (score 2):

Old thread, I know, but from what I can see, the answer is to precompile manually before pushing to heroku.  I did this after a lot of searching and it worked for me.

```
$ RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

I put this in the terminal just before the git add.  I also restarted the heroku dyno.

Answer (score 1):

You should at least two things: stop loading duplicate files (CDN combined with a GEM) and reorganize your `application.js` file so **Bootstrap** is required after **jQuery**.

The `<head>` section of your application.html.erb should be something closer to this:

```
<head>
  <title>ShiftInd</title>
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag     'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
```

With the exception of jQuery-UI, you allready have a GEM loading these files and some of these have duplicates from a CDN as well. And your own stylesheets should be added to `application.scss` using `@import`.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"></link>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

You're pulling in files with CDNs while also using GEMs to implement the same files (jQuery/Font Awesome, etc.).

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.2.3'
gem 'devise'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'mailboxer'
gem 'chosen-rails'
gem 'acts_as_votable', '~> 0.10.0'
gem 'public_activity'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'coffee-script-source', '1.8.0'
gem 'paperclip', '~> 4.3.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.5.1'
gem "autoprefixer-rails"
gem 'font-awesome-sass', '~> 4.4.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

group :production do
    gem 'pg'
    gem 'rails_12factor'
end

group :development, :test do
    gem 'sqlite3'
end

# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Here's a new version of your Gemfile to use as a reference: I changed a few things which you don't have to do but may help in general:

- Switched [Font-Awesome](https://github.com/FortAwesome/font-awesome-sass) Gems
- Added [Autoprefixer](https://github.com/ai/autoprefixer-rails) See [Bootstrap-sass](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass) Gem

> Bootstrap requires the use of Autoprefixer. Autoprefixer adds vendor
>   prefixes to CSS rules using values from Can I Use.

- Added [Jquery-UI](https://github.com/joliss/jquery-ui-rails) Gem (You can also use the CDN if you want, this is just another option. Original files for reference below.)

  ```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  ```

In your application.js, Bootstrap needs to be after jQuery. See the [Docs](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass).

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require chosen-jquery
//= require bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

This is an example application.scss.

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
@import "font-awesome-sprockets";
@import "font-awesome";
@import "jquery-ui";
@import 'style';
```

*Your `style.css`, needs to be changed to `style.scss`

Comment: thanks sir but as am new to rails can you please elaborate what i need to remove to get this done @vanburen

Comment: i did as you said but it doesn't worked and one more thing there is no file called assets.css @vanburen

Comment: Did you run bundle again or bundle update after your changes? I really don't know what else to tell you other then to post the url it's hosted on with Heroku. And it should be style.css inside the assets folder.

Comment: yes i run bundle install... one more thing as i was trying to run heroku run rake assets:precompile after this change i got this error
rake aborted!
Sprockets::FileNotFound: couldn't find file 'jquery.turbolinks'
http://shiftind.herokuapp.com @vanburen

Comment: If you look at the page source, jquery is still being loading after Bootstrap inside your script file. And when I use your HTML output, the navbar-toggle button ID is broken `#bs-example-navbar- collapse-1`, there shouldn't be any gaps.

Comment: i had added application.html.erb in my question can you please tell me where the gap is needed sir @vanburen

Comment: It's the same as the comment above: inside your `navbar` find `data-target="#bs-example-navbar-  collapse-1"` and there's a gap between `navbar-` and `collapse-1`.

Comment: so i just have to delete that gap?? @vanburen

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95057/discussion-between-vanburen-and-denial-smith).